# Resolver doesn't work as expected

Tags: angular, angular-router

I created a resolver and except that all components will load after the resolver will be finish to run, but the components are sometimes loaded before the resolver function is done.

The resolver code is:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { ApiService } from '../services';
import { AppState } from 'spotlightcloud-angular-common-website';
import { Locale } from '../locale/locale';

@Injectable()
export class MetricsLocaleResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(public api: ApiService, public appState: AppState, private locale: Locale) {
  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
    return this.api.get('monitoring', 'uiconfiguration/metricsmetadata', {}).subscribe(
      localeData => {
        console.log('localeData: ', localeData);
        this.locale.setMetricsLocaleObj(localeData);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

The `localeData` print sometimes appears after the print in the component (in `onChanges` lifecycle).

Comment: What is calling `resolve` on the `MetricsLocaleResolver` instance? Your components?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
return this.api.get('monitoring', 'uiconfiguration/metricsmetadata', {}).subscribe(
```

to

```
return this.api.get('monitoring', 'uiconfiguration/metricsmetadata', {}).map(
```

If you call `.subscribe()` you return a `Subscription`, the router expects an `Observable`, `Promise`, or `boolean` value instead.

The callback also should return a boolean value

```
  localeData => {
    console.log("localeData:",localeData);
    this.locale.setMetricsLocaleObj(localeData);
    return true;
  }
```